# Is there an html tag for foreword

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a site that has quite a few articles and wanting to have forewords in the more important ones, I've had a search and can't find anything that seems to identify what to do for this. All I can think of is using bold tags...
Is there an html tag for foreword and if not, what's the most semantic way to tag this?

EXAMPLE

```
<p>
    <foreword>
        The start of the article would go in here, typically the first sentence of the article.
    </foreword>
    Rest of the text for the article would go here.
</p>
```

Comment: Why not use two p tags within

Comment: @TejasPatel I didn't know you could use p tags within, thanks for that.

Comment: You can't nest p tags, that's invalid html. A paragraph is a standalone, block-level, element. You can't put one inside another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By forward do you mean introductory text?    One option is to put it in a header element.

```
<article>
    <header>
      <h1>My Title</h1>
      <h5>A really dull article on organic gardening</h5>
    </header>
    <section>       
        Organic gardening is.....etc. etc. etc.
    </section>
 </article>
```

Comment: +1 although it's worth pointing out that a heading element isn't appropriate for a subtitle or a tagline - it can be marked up as a paragraph instead, even though it isn't really one.

Comment: @BoltClock — I think it IS appropriate...at least that's what all the articles say...and the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080122/#the-header.  "The header element represents the header of a section. Headers may contain more than just the section's heading — for example it would be reasonable for the header to include version history information."  "Other heading elements in the header element indicate subheadings or subtitles."

Comment: Perhaps it was fine, six years ago, but it's now expressly disallowed: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-idioms.html#sub-head "h1–h6 elements **must not** be used to markup subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines unless intended to be the heading for a new section or subsection." You're only introducing one new section here, so using two heading elements is inappropriate.

Comment: Ah...OK.   When you said 'heading element' I thought you meant the <header> tag and what you really meant were the <h1> <h2>...etc. tags.  But I think having one new section is still a new section so I think it meets the specification.   But I'm not an html lawyer.

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't.

If you are looking to create a visually distinct lead paragraph then simply add a class that you can use to apply that styling, e.g.:

```
<p class="foreword">
```

I apply a visual intro style on my blog posts, using just a little CSS, eg:

```
.intro, 
.post p:first-of-type {font-size: 1.3125em;}
```

The first paragraph in any post, or any element that I give the class .intro then adopts this visual style. Here's an example: http://internet-inspired.com/wrote/load-disqus-on-demand/

Semantically it's no different to any other paragraph though.

You should certainly not use bold tags, they do carry a semantic meaning and should not simply be used for the purpose of adding weight to your copy. To alter the visual appearance you should use only css.

Of course, html5 won't freak out of you do use a foreword tag, it wouldn't cause an error, but it just won't *do* anything. And it would carry less semantic value than a p tag, making it utterly pointless.

Comment: Are you sure non-standard elements constitute valid HTML5? The only user-defined element spec I can think of is Web Components, but I don't think that's what you're referring to.

Comment: No, you are correct. What I should have said, and I corrected my answer above, is that it wouldn't cause an explicit error. html5 is very forgiving in that respect. The full list of defined elements can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/elements.html

Answer (score 1):

According to HTML5 CR, the [`header` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element) “represents introductory content for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element”, and a foreword can obviously be regarded as introductory. The description adds: “A header typically contains a group of introductory or navigational aids.” However, this is not meant to restrict the use to such “aids”, whatever that might mean. There is an example of a `header` element containing a greeting:

```
<header>
 <p>Welcome to...</p>
 <h1>Voidwars!</h1>
</header>
```

However, a `header` element is a collective element, typically containing a heading and something else. If that something else is (or contains) a foreword, there is no dedicated element for the foreword. It can be made a `section` element, but that’s general thematic grouping and not specifically any particular content. So you would use something like this:

```
<article>
<header>
  <h2>Treatise on human misunderstanding</h2>
  <section class=foreword>
    The foreword goes here. It typically consists of a few paragraphs and a footer.
  </section>
</header>
<section>The first section of the article.</section>
<section>The second section of the article.</section>
<section>And so on.</section>
</article>
```

However, since you say you considered using “bold tags” and show the dummy content of the “foreword” as “The start of the article would go in here, typically the first sentence of the article.”, it seems that you don’t actually mean a foreword at all. According to [Merriam-Webster description](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foreword), a foreword is “a section at the beginning of a book that introduces the book and is usually written by someone other than the book's author”.

I think you actually meant a headline. However, this really does not change much structurally. It could still be wrapped in a `header` element and even marked up as `section`, though that would not be very natural. A single-sentence “section” isn’t much of a section; rather, it could be a `p` element or just a `div` element, e.g. `<div class=headline>...</div>`.

This is all somewhat theoretical. The `header` element has no known impact on anything except being a block element (and its content normally causes block rendering anyway). The same applies to `section`. Use them if you like, but don’t expect them to “do” anything. You can use them in styling, but you could style `div` elements just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean using forward links from one page to other? If yes, then use following anchor tag:

```
<a href="URL_Of_Page_You_Want_To_Go_To">Name_You_Want_To_Give_To_The_Link</a>
```

Eg-->

```
Click <a href="newPage.html">here</a>
```

or

```
Click <a href="newPage.jsp">here</a>
```

Comment: I mean in some paragraph tags adding in foreword tags, I've will add an example to the question